# How to integrate Magento 2.3.2 with ERP without SOAP

Tags: magento, integration, magento2, crm, erp

What are the options to integrate a ERP system with my online store? It is a local company, not a big tech like SAP Business One or NetSuite etc etc. I've asked if they can provide me with SOAP access but they cannot, I am still waiting for their reply but I would like to hear an opinion from someone who faced such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an ftp folder and import export the different business objects you need to sync.
For example: stock, customers, products etc.
Then you will need to create a cronjob that runs the magento console command with the import or export routine.
You can also create in magento a new cron task.

Comment: You mean like export them in SQL format and import them in the website database?

Comment: No magento db structure it is very complex in magento1 was a very good tool to do this call magmi but in m2 it is in develpment https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2.  What i sugest it is to export import trough csv files